# Error en el bucleWhile

Tags: java

Al compilar el programa me devuelve un error en el while:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Programa {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   public main bucleWhile(int x=5) {
      int y = 2;
      int z = -2;
      while (x + 3 > y) {
         y = y + 2;
         z++;
      }
      System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);
   }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La linea donde escribes

```
             public main bucleWhile(int x=5)
```

esta mal, no se que intestaste hacer, parece que invocar un metodo, en realidad no se.
Esto es lo que creo que querias hacer

```
      public class Programa {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         int x=5;
         int y = 2;
         int z = -2;
         while (x + 3 > y) {
           y = y + 2;
           z++;
         }
         System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);
     }
```

}